# Pass data from Android Native to React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I am building an integrated app with Android native and React native communicating with each other.

For sending data from Native to React native I tried to pass data by using initial props but it was not working and showing undefined. Then I tried to use DeviceEventEmitter which kind of worked but there was a slight problem.

**EDITED :**

Here's the **code snippet**:

```
class Details extends Component {

    constructor(props){
    super(props);
            this.state={data: '', id: '278'}
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter();
        this.subscription = eventEmitter.addListener('customEventName',(e: Event)=>{
            this.setState({id: e.key1});
            console.warn(this.state.id);    
        });

        const API_key = "APIkey"
        console.warn(this.state.id);

        const URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + this.state.id + "?api_key=" + API_key + "&language=en-USs"

        return fetch(URL, {
          method: 'GET'
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          this.setState({
            data: responseJson,
          },
          function(){
          });
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
          console.error(error);
        });
     }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.subscription.remove();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            /*something*/
        );
    }
}
```

The value of id is being successfully sent from native component to React native component.

**Problem:** The `console.warn()` inside `addlistener()` is showing after the `console.warn()` which is below declaring the `API_key`, and hence the `this.state.id` is not being updated.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Also I tried using id as state but it did not work since apparently the DeviceEventEmiiter does not allows to use setState() method.

Why ?

Comment: it's showing a warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. TO fix, cancell all subsciptions and asynchronous tasks in 'the componeneWillUnmount method'

Comment: Please check I updated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your event register should be something as mentioned below, as you are registering the event so the scope of `this` should be event handler specific so if you want to access the parent scope you need to use the arrow function like mentioned below.

```
 DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('customEventName',(e: Event)=> {
        this.id = e.key1
        console.warn("inside event emitter", this.id);
    });
```

Comment: sorry but it's still not working, also tried to put the DeviceEventEmitter inside componentDidMount() but did not worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are successfully getting the event then I think this is just a React problem.

It looks like you want to fetch *after* you have successfully got the ID, but you're trying to fetch straight away in `componentDidMount`.

As fetch is a side effect you probably want to use `componentDidUpdate` like so:

```js
import { NativeEventEmitter } from 'react-native'

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        data: '', 
        id: ''
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter();
        this.subscription = eventEmitter.addListener('customEventName',(e: Event)=>{
            this.setState({id: e.key1});
            console.warn(this.state.id);    
        });
     }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      const { id } = this.state

      if (id) {
       const URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + this.state.id + "?api_key=" + API_key + "&language=en-USs"

        return fetch(URL, {
          method: 'GET'
        })
       // ... etc
      }
    }

    // ...etc
```

Note that `id` starts out as empty.